# How to parse and replace Russian words and phrases in an html file?

Tags: php, parsing

there was a problem when trying to parse and replace Russian words with special tags for localizing the project.

Сode was written on the knee for parsing the necessary html pages line by line

Please help to compose the correct regular expression to replace Russian words and phrases in a loop
**foreach ($lines as $line)**

```
$dir = 'Mydir :)';
        
function files($path){

    $dir = opendir($path."/.");

    while($item = readdir($dir))
      if(is_file($sub = $path."/".$item))
          $files[] = $path."/".$item;
        else
           if($item != "." and $item != "..")
           files($sub,$files);

    return($files);
}

$alldirs = files($dir);

foreach ($alldirs as $el){
 $filename = $el;
   if (file_exists($filename) && is_readable($filename)) {
    $lines = @file($filename);
     foreach ($lines as $line){
       // help please 
     }
   }
}
```

Html example for parsing

```
 <div class="navbar-nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="cap">INTRODUCTION</li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?agreements">Условия и соглашения</a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/">Начало работы с API</a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?action=akeylist">API-ключи</a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?action=callback">Callback</a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?samples">Примеры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?action=stat">Тесовое словосочетание</a></li>
        <li class="cap">METHODS</li>
        <li class="cap">OBJECTS</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

example of end result:

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="cap"><fq name='testword1'/><!--the russian word has been replaced with a tag with a specific name--></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?agreements"><fq name='testword2'/><!--the russian word has been replaced with a tag with a specific name--></a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/"><fq name='testword3'/><!--the russian word has been replaced with a tag with a specific name--></a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?action=akeylist"><fq name='testword4'/><!--the russian word has been replaced with a tag with a specific name--></a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?action=callback"><fq name='testword5'/><!--the russian word has been replaced with a tag with a specific name--></a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?samples"><fq name='testword6'/><!--the russian word has been replaced with a tag with a specific name--></a></li>
        <li><a href="/lk/api/?action=stat"><fq name='testword7'/><!--the russian word has been replaced with a tag with a specific name--></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: it is necessary to parse html templates and replace Russian words and phrases in them with a tag ```<fq name='some name'/>``` Сorrected the description of the final result

Comment: you would be better off not using Russian text at all and instead use placeholders which link to keywords in a language file, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61992263/implementation-of-multilanguage-in-php/61992582#61992582

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing HTML with regular expressions. Use a parser such as XMLReader or DOMDocument

Answer (score 0):

if double tag was in line. this gonna change the value between the innermost tags.

it works for your exmaple. but in some situation this may not work.

```
$replacedLines = [];
$regex = '/(<.+>)([^<]+)(<\/.+>)/';

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $replacement = "<fq name='testword'/>";
    $replacedLines[] = preg_replace($regex, "$1$replacement$3", $line);
}
```

for a more universal way you can use xml parser. `$text` is your html string and `$html` is the result.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($text);
$stack = [$xml];
$i = 0;
while(count($stack)) {
    $node = array_pop($stack);
    foreach($node as $child) {
        if(!$child->count()) {
            $i++;
            $child->children()[0] = '';
            $child->addChild('fq')->addAttribute('name', "testword$i");
        }else {
            array_push($stack, $child);
        }
    }
}
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
$html = $dom->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom->ownerDocument->documentElement);
```